# Within a dataframe, how do I select specific variables for further computation based solely on their names?

Tags: r, dplyr

Using `dplyr`, is there a way to select the variables with names ending with `_p` and `_ln` and multiplying them with their corresponding variables? For example, I am trying to get three different variables, the first would be a result of multiplying `A_p` with `A_ln`, the second a multiple of `B_p` with `B_ln`. I am finding it difficult to pinpoint with precision the named variables I need because of the three variables `A`, `B`, and `C`, which I have to keep in the dataset.

dput() output:
`structure(list(id = structure(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10), label = "id", format.spss = "F4.0", display_width = 0L), A = c(13, 9, 14, 14, 13), B = c(12, 0, 9, 3, 10), C = c(13, 8, 14, 13, 11), total = c(38, 17, 37, 30, 34), A_p = c(2, 5, 3, 6, 10), B_p = c(5, 3, 6, 10, 2), C_p = c(3, 6, 10, 2, 5), A_ln = c(10, 2, 5, 3, 6), B_ln = c(10, 2, 5, 1, 2), C_ln = c(2, 8, 10, 2, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use dplyr's rowwise() and c_across as in the following example which creates three columns which are the products of the columns beginning with "A_", "B_", and "C_" respectively.

```
library(tidyverse)

structure(list(id = structure(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10), label = "id", 
                              format.spss = "F4.0", display_width = 0L), 
               A = c(13, 9, 14, 14, 13), 
               B = c(12, 0, 9, 3, 10), 
               C = c(13, 8, 14, 13, 11), 
               total = c(38, 17, 37, 30, 34), 
               A_p = c(2, 5, 3, 6, 10), 
               B_p = c(5, 3, 6, 10, 2), 
               C_p = c(3, 6, 10, 2, 5), 
               A_ln = c(10, 2, 5, 3, 6), 
               B_ln = c(10, 2, 5, 1, 2), 
               C_ln = c(2, 8, 10, 2, 5)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    A_product = prod(c_across(starts_with("A_"))),
    B_product = prod(c_across(starts_with("B_"))),
    C_product = prod(c_across(starts_with("C_"))),
    )
```

If you want just the columns with the products, you can simply add:

```
%>% select(A_product, B_product, C_product)
```

Comment: Thanks @Blue050205. Is there any way I could use the ```rowwise()``` and ```prod(c_across())``` functions inside a loop? I am working with a dataset that requires me to compute the products for varying number of items, and I am trying to write a function that let me do so, but I am having a lot of difficulty using loops inside ```dplyr```. I tried writing a loop function before, then calling the loop, but it turns up an error: ```c_across() must only be used inside dplyr verbs```.

Comment: @Bear25 - What are you trying to achieve with the loops?  Can you provide an example of a desired result?

Answer (score 1):

This example subsets your initial data into two matrices, which you can multiply, then just fix the names.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

dat <- structure(list(id = structure(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10), label = "id", format.spss = "F4.0", display_width = 0L), A = c(13, 9, 14, 14, 13), B = c(12, 0, 9, 3, 10), C = c(13, 8, 14, 13, 11), total = c(38, 17, 37, 30, 34), A_p = c(2, 5, 3, 6, 10), B_p = c(5, 3, 6, 10, 2), C_p = c(3, 6, 10, 2, 5), A_ln = c(10, 2, 5, 3, 6), B_ln = c(10, 2, 5, 1, 2), C_ln = c(2, 8, 10, 2, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

(select(dat, matches("_ln")) * 
  select(dat, matches("_p"))) %>%
   rename_with(.fn = function(x) gsub("_ln","",x))
#>    A  B   C
#> 1 20 50   6
#> 2 10  6  48
#> 3 15 30 100
#> 4 18 10   4
#> 5 60  4  25
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure this is what you are after but a bit of data wrangling can help to get a summary `data.frame` you can later bind to the original one if needed.

```
library(dplyr)
# your data
df <- structure(list(id = structure(c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10), label = "id", format.spss = "F4.0", display_width = 0L), A = c(13, 9, 14, 14, 13), B = c(12, 0, 9, 3, 10), C = c(13, 8, 14, 13, 11), total = c(38, 17, 37, 30, 34), A_p = c(2, 5, 3, 6, 10), B_p = c(5, 3, 6, 10, 2), C_p = c(3, 6, 10, 2, 5), A_ln = c(10, 2, 5, 3, 6), B_ln = c(10, 2, 5, 1, 2), C_ln = c(2, 8, 10, 2, 5)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# select the columns according to your pattern
df %>% select(id, ends_with("_p"), ends_with("_ln")) %>% 
# pivot everything into a long format, keeping the id column
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
# separate the variables, we do this because you want the A "_p" to multiply the A of "_ln" and we will group by letter to do this
  tidyr::separate(col = "name", into=c("letter", "end"), sep="_") %>%
# don't forget to group by id, so values are multiplied within id 
  group_by(id, letter) %>% 
  summarise(prod_value = prod(value))
```

This produces

```
# A tibble: 15 x 3
# Groups:   id [5]
      id letter prod_value
   <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>
 1     2 A              20
 2     2 B              50
 3     2 C               6
 4     4 A              10
 5     4 B               6
 6     4 C              48
 7     6 A              15
 8     6 B              30
 9     6 C             100
10     8 A              18
11     8 B              10
12     8 C               4
13    10 A              60
14    10 B               4
15    10 C              25
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
bind_cols(df, map2_dfc(grep('_p$', names(df), value = 1), grep('_ln$', names(df), value = 1), ~{
   new_col <- paste0(.x,.y)
   df %>% 
     transmute(!!new_col := .data[[.x]]*.data[[.y]])
 }))
# A tibble: 5 x 14
     id     A     B     C total   A_p   B_p   C_p  A_ln  B_ln  C_ln A_pA_ln B_pB_ln C_pC_ln
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     2    13    12    13    38     2     5     3    10    10     2      20      50       6
2     4     9     0     8    17     5     3     6     2     2     8      10       6      48
3     6    14     9    14    37     3     6    10     5     5    10      15      30     100
4     8    14     3    13    30     6    10     2     3     1     2      18      10       4
5    10    13    10    11    34    10     2     5     6     2     5      60       4      25
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it often easier to use column numbers and base R:

```
newcols <- df[ , 6:8] * df[ , 9:11]
names(newcols) <- c('A_prod', 'B_prod', 'C_prod')
cbind(df, newcols)
  id  A  B  C total A_p B_p C_p A_ln B_ln C_ln A_prod B_prod C_prod
1  2 13 12 13    38   2   5   3   10   10    2     20     50      6
2  4  9  0  8    17   5   3   6    2    2    8     10      6     48
3  6 14  9 14    37   3   6  10    5    5   10     15     30    100
4  8 14  3 13    30   6  10   2    3    1    2     18     10      4
5 10 13 10 11    34  10   2   5    6    2    5     60      4     25
```